# associative array in vba like php

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

I need your help for building analytics in Microsoft Excel using VBA.

I have one data sheet with y columns and n lines

```
Line Number  Firstname  Lastname  Country  Training Hours  Training Status
1            John       Smith     USA      1               Completed
2            Henri      Dupont    France   1               Completed
3            Paul       Walker    USA      25              Incomplete
4            Ron        Howard    USA      10              Completed
```

And I would like to use array like in php but using VBA

```vb
For i = 1 To nblines
    If(array[i]["Country"] = "USA" And array[i]["Training Status"] = "Completed") Then
        myval = myval + array[i]["Training Hours"]
    End If
Next
```

myval should be 11

Unfortunately I don't find THE solution. I've tried dictionnary, collection and array but without success. Any idea?

Comment: Have you considered putting this data in a table and pointing a pivot table at it? Or using a `SUMIFS` formula? Either could address the added information that you gave in Scott Craner's answer. No VBA needed and more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the SQL query to the worksheet in the opened workbook (the same way as to any other workbook). In this case the query string will be as follows:

```sql
SELECT SUM([Training Hours]) AS Myval FROM [data sheet$] WHERE Country = 'USA' AND [Training Status] = 'Completed';
```

Here is the code

```vb
Sub TestSQLRequest()

    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adCmdText = &H1

    Select Case LCase(Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".")))
        Case ".xls"
            strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"
        Case ".xlsm"
            strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;"";"
    End Select

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        .Open strConnection
        With .Execute("SELECT SUM([Training Hours]) AS Myval FROM [data sheet$] WHERE Country = 'USA' AND [Training Status] = 'Completed';")
            Myval = .Fields("Myval")
        End With
        .Close
    End With

    MsgBox Myval

End Sub
```

Within the query string, the column names with spaces should be put into square brackets, as well as the name of the worksheet containing data followed by `$`.
It goes without saying that the query can't access to the data, which wasn't saved to the file after some changes have been made to the sheet.
Note that `Excel 8.0` provider won't work on 64-bit Excel version, try to use `Excel 12.0` provider instead (the second `strConnection` assignment).

Comment: Thanks a lot omegastripes, it works perfectly. It is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

So I set my sheet up like this:

[image]

Then using the following code I loaded the array and cycled through each line in the array.  I added the Hours as they met the condition and displayed the result in the immediate window.

Edit: As far as I know excel does not use column names.  So the only way I could come up with is this, Where we add the first row into the array then cycle through them looking for the names in the first row of the array to get the position of that column then use the variable to find again.

A quicker method would likely be an advanced filter with subtotals.  Filter on a different page than the data.  Or, the best answer would be using a pivot table.

```
Sub nubuk()

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim smTtl As Double
Dim i&
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcolumn
Dim t&
Dim cntry&, stus&, hrs&

With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn = Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print lastcolumn
    arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Value
End With
For t = 1 To lastcolumn
    Select Case LCase(arr(1, t))
        Case "country"
            cntry = t
        Case "training status"
            stus = t
        Case "training hours"
            hrs = t
        Case Else
    End Select
Next t
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(i, cntry) = "USA" And arr(i, stus) = "Completed" Then
        smTtl = smTtl + arr(i, hrs)
    End If
Next

Debug.Print smTtl

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Scott and thank you for your help. The problem is that my sheet of data can change and the order of the columns can be changed. 
For example

Line Number|Country|Firstname|Lastname|Training Status|Training Hours
1|USA|John|Smith|USA|Completed|1
2|France|Henri|Dupont|France|Completed|1
3|USA|Paul|Walker|USA|Incomplete|25
4|USA|Ron|Howard|Completed|10 

That's why I want to work with column header and not column number. Any idea ?

Comment: Nice approach Scott. Thanks a lot for your help. I will use an array with the  column name used for filter and make a loop on it to get the column number.

Comment: FYI as omegastripes said, you can make the data into an Excel table and then use column names directly in your code to access them.

Comment: Hi omegastripes and MacroMarc,
I will use an xls file and I want to store the filter used with values, the result needed : a sum, an average, a count in a cell to calculate dynamically the result. 
For example : I want to put in the cell G1 the result and the formula in the cell H1 to be re-editing later
filter:country;equal;USA
filter:training status;equal;Completed
result:sum;training hours
That's why I can't use a pivot table.

Maybe MacroMarc you can provide me an example.