# Running an MS Query on the current Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, oledb

**How to run an MS Query (Ace Oledb) on the current Excel workbook without having to specify an external data source in the connection string? i.e Data Source file path**

Below is my full connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data 
Source=C:\myfile.xlsm;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 
Xml;HDR=YES";Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global 
Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New 
Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet 
OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on 
Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet 
OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass 
UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet 
OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False
```

I would like to remove this reference `Data Source=C:\myfile.xlsm` **making the connection string assume it should always reference the current Excel file**.

What I want is to be able to setup an MS Query in my Excel file that can be shared via email to other users. Currently I need to programatically (VBA) replace the Data Source in the connection string which is not an elegant solution. I want to avoid any need of vba usage.

Comment: Please show the code where you are assigning that connection string to a variable. Generally, it should be like `strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data 
Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Mode=ReadWrite;..."`, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33400291/2165759). If you need to sort or filter records only, then [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36189658/2165759) may be helpful.

Comment: The file needs to be saved somewhere on disk before you can use a SQL query against it, and you need to pass the actual file path in the connection string.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to omit by needing to specify the data source programmatically. Is there no other way I.e. by using Power Queen or sorts. It seems like a pretty obvious scenario. Even changing the name or location of the Excel workbook the macro needs to update the data source

Comment: It's not clear why you really don't want to use the obvious solution?

Comment: @TimWilliams because the obvious solution is not to use VBA if that is possible. Even if I pass the actual file path if I save the file with a new name or send it via email it work work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Hummmm, can you put `Data Source=C:\myfile.xlsm` into a cell reference and pass that as a parameter?

STRING " & Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & " STRING

Comment: This does not solve the issue in any way. This still requires manual update of the cell reference.