# Add multiple values to Dictionary .VBA

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

i am a absolute newbie in VBA. I want to add more than one value in the Dictonary to group a table with the same values by the Amount of the items.
So I have this table

```
1   10  A5  Text1   Audi1   Auto1   100
2   10  A5  Text1   Audi1   Auto1   100
3   10  A5  Text1   Audi1   Auto1   100
4   10  A4  Text4   Audi4   Auto4   200
5   10  A6  Text5   Audi5   Auto5   300
6   10  A6  Text5   Text5   Text5   300
7   10  A5  Text1   Audi1   Auto1   100
8   10  A4  Text4   Audi4   Auto4   200
9   10  A2  Text9   Audi9   Auto9   50
10  10  A1  Text10  Audi10  Auto10  25
```

now i want to group then together an it should look like this:

```
1   40  A5  Text1   Audi1   Auto1   100    
2   20  A4  Text4   Audi4   Auto4   200    
3   20  A6  Text5   Audi5   Auto5   300    
4   10  A2  Text9   Audi9   Auto9   50    
5   10  A1  Text10  Audi10  Auto10  25
```

My actaul VBA is this:

```
Sub Schaltfläche1_Klicken()

Dim WkSh    As Worksheet
Dim aTemp   As Variant
Dim lZeile  As Long
Dim rZelle  As Range
Dim Dict    As Variant

   Set WkSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

   With WkSh ' die Fahrzeuge aus A2:Bn in einen temporären Array schreiben
      aTemp = .Range("B13:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
   End With

   WkSh.Range("B13:G1000").ClearContents ' den Bereich D2:E100 leeren/löschen

   Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   On Error Resume Next

'     die Daten an das Dictionary übergeben
   For lZeile = 1 To UBound(aTemp)
      Dict(aTemp(lZeile, 2)) = Dict(aTemp(lZeile, 2)) + aTemp(lZeile, 1)
      Next lZeile
'
'    ausgeben
'
   Set rZelle = WkSh.Cells(13, 2) ' Bereich festlegen wo hingeschrieben werden soll Beispiel: cells(5,1) -> Reihe 5 Spalte 1
'
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   rZelle.Resize(Dict.Count) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dict.Items)
   rZelle.Offset(0, 1).Resize(Dict.Count) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dict.Keys)
   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

And give me this Output:

```
1   40  A5
2   20  A4
3   20  A6
4   10  A2
5   10  A1
```

Can someone please help me, to achive my wanted output.

Comment: It is better to use adodb and SQL to get the sum. You will then need to know the field name.

Comment: The Audi and Auto columns seem to contain 2 extra Text5 values

Comment: Remove that    On Error Resume Next in case any errors are being masked.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33400291/2165759) SQL solution.

Comment: In the original sample data is the 1 or the 10 in B13?

Comment: As mentioned by Slai there are some extra values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dictionary. The dictionary keys are created from the concatenation of columns B:F. If the key is already present then the column A value is added to the existing value for that key.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTotals()
    Dim inputRange As Range, dict As Object, arr(), i As Long, uniqueKey As String, ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set inputRange = ws.Range("A1:F10")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arr = inputRange.Value

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        uniqueKey = arr(i, 2) & "," & arr(i, 3) & "," & arr(i, 4) & "," & arr(i, 5) & "," & arr(i, 6)
        dict(uniqueKey) = dict(uniqueKey) + arr(i, 1)
    Next i
    Dim key As Variant, tempArr() As String, rowCounter As Long
    rowCounter = inputRange.Offset(inputRange.Rows.Count + 2, 0).Row

    With ws
        For Each key In dict.keys
            .Cells(rowCounter, 1) = dict(key)
            tempArr = Split(key, ",")
            .Cells(rowCounter, 2).Resize(1, UBound(tempArr) + 1) = tempArr
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        Next key
    End With

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Version outputing only 2 columns and ignoring the additional unwanted row:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTotals()
    Dim inputRange As Range, dict As Object, arr(), i As Long, uniqueKey As String, ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set inputRange = ws.Range("A1:F10")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arr = inputRange.Value

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not (arr(i, 4)) = "Text5" Then
            uniqueKey = arr(i, 2) & "," & arr(i, 3) & "," & arr(i, 4) & "," & arr(i, 5) & "," & arr(i, 6)
            dict(uniqueKey) = dict(uniqueKey) + arr(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    Dim key As Variant, tempArr() As String, rowCounter As Long
    rowCounter = inputRange.Offset(inputRange.Rows.Count + 2, 0).Row

    With ws
        For Each key In dict.keys
            .Cells(rowCounter, 1) = dict(key)
            tempArr = Split(key, ",")

            .Cells(rowCounter, 2) = tempArr(0)
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
        Next key
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Version 1: Data in at top. Data out at bottom.

[image: Data]

Version 2: 2 columns; ignore error.

[image: Data2]

Comment: It works but not completely. how can i change the position where i want to put the new output. the rowcounter give me the offset position, but how can i say i want to put the output on ws.Cells(26,2) for example?

Comment: This line determines where I started outputing:  rowCounter = inputRange.Offset(inputRange.Rows.Count + 2, 0).Row

Comment: simply say rowCounter = 26 to start at row 26.

Comment: But i will accept this for correct answer because the other thing is only optimizing

Comment: .Cells(rowCounter, 1) = dict(key)  is putting the key in column A so if you want key in column B then use  .Cells(rowCounter, 2) = dict(key) and  .Cells(rowCounter,3) = tempArr(0)  That will shift everything to the right one column. The rowCounter just says which row to start writing out at. Put it at what ever value you would like e.g. 26.

Comment: Alright, now it works correctly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Pleasure. Happy to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Another Scripting.Dictionary based solution.

```
Sub Schaltfläche1_Klicken()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, tmp As String
    Dim aTemp  As Variant, dict As Object

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        aTemp = .Range(.Cells(13, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)).Value2
        .Range(.Cells(13, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)).ClearContents

        Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        dict.comparemode = vbBinaryCompare

        For i = LBound(aTemp, 1) To UBound(aTemp, 1)
            tmp = Join(Array(aTemp(i, 2), aTemp(i, 3), aTemp(i, 4), aTemp(i, 5), aTemp(i, 6)), ChrW(8203))
            dict.Item(tmp) = dict.Item(tmp) + aTemp(i, 1)
        Next i

        With .Cells(13, "B").Resize(dict.Count, 1)
            .Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 1) = 1
            .Offset(0, -1).Resize(dict.Count, 1).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, _
                    Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1, Stop:=dict.Count
            .Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.keys)
            .Offset(0, 1).TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(0, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                                        Other:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
                                        OtherChar:=ChrW(8203), FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1))
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```